# Site icons broken in Stack Overflow/Star Wars Trilogy blog post

Tags: bug, status-completed, blog

There should be site icons (I assume) in the blog post [The Stack Overflow Trilogy](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/05/31/the-stack-overflow-trilogy/), but they're broken:

> [image]

I also noticed the following problems on the same page:

- It looks truly awful [on mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBkuM.jpg)
- The text that says "superuser.com" is a little smaller than the other two sites
- The following links are HTTP when they could be HTTPS:
- site links (http://stackoverflow.com/, http://serverfault.com/, and http://superuser.com/)
- the link for "naming is hard" (https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/03/it-stack-overflow-update-naming-is-hard/)
- Jeff's website link (http://blog.codinghorror.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for letting us know about the broken images and non-HTTPS links.  I've updated the post as you suggested.